# scroll to a div on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to scroll the page upon a `.click` event. Here is what I have so far:

jQuery:

```
function scrollToStart() {
    $("#scrollToStart").click(function() {
      $("#startHere").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
      return false;
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#startHere" id="scrollToStart">
    <img class="img-center" src="images/get-started.png"/>
</a>
```

When I click, it doesn't do anything. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have jsfiddle?

Comment: because your scrolling always on top of the page.  try chaning `scrollTop: 0 ` to `scrollTop: 500`

Comment: When does `scrollToStart()` get called. You are only binding to the `.click` handler after that gets called. You should move this into a doc ready handler

Comment: why not using an anchor? => http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.3

Comment: @RGraham - It gets called in a different part of the script. This is just one part of it.

Comment: What browser are you using? It doesn't work in IE.

Comment: @relentless You'd either need to show where `scrollToStart` gets called, or prove to us it gets called by adding a breakpoint/`console.log` in there - otherwise the problem could be elsewhere in your code

Comment: @RGraham I checked with a `console.log` just before posting. It's getting called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work

```
$("#scrollToStart").click(function (){
       $('html, body').animate({
       crollTop: $("#startHere").offset().top
     }, 2000);

});
```

a working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tvTUu/

Comment: well bit it does work .. :) i have created a js fiddle for that

Comment: maybe you are using a normal anchor `href="#startHere"` ?!! in that case you have to `return false;` on click . to `preventDefault` and event bubbling

Comment: Typo my friend ;) Just saw it `crollTop`. I fixed it in my code, works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('html,body').animate({    
 scrollTop: $("#divToBeScrolledTo").offset().top;    
});
```

with `scrollTop: 0` you always scroll to the top of the page.

More information you can find here (With live-Demo):
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){// when dom loaded
    $("#scrollToStart").click(function (){
       $(document.body).animate({
          scrollTop: 0
       });
    });
});
```

I works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question properly, you need to scroll your page to the top position on the click event, with an animation effect. I did something similar not long ago, here is the JavaScript code.

```
innerAnimationStep = 25;
innerScrollStep = 1;

function scrollTopAnimated(scrollStep, animationStep)
{
    try
    {
        innerScrollStep = scrollStep;
        innerAnimationStep = animationStep;
        scrollTopAnimationStep();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}

function scrollTopAnimationStep()
{   
    try
    {
        var jDocument = $(document); 
        if(jDocument.scrollTop() > 0)
        {
            jDocument.scrollTop( jDocument.scrollTop() - innerScrollStep );
            setTimeout(scrollTopAnimationStep, innerAnimationStep);
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

Just call `scrollTopAnimated` to get the page scroll with animated effect. I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#scrollToStart").bind('click',function() {

$('body , html').animate(
  {
    scrollTop :  $("#startHere").offset().top
  } , 2000 ) ;
});
```

http://justprogrammer.com/2013/06/21/scroll-to-specifically-element-in-browser/
http://justprogrammer.com/2013/06/25/jquery-basic-concepts/

Answer (score -1):

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
$("#scrollToStart").click(function() {
  $("#startHere").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});});
```